# Matplotlib failure

Tags: python, matplotlib

whenever I try and plot a simple graph in the standard python interpreter,
matplotlib doesn't plot it all, all it does is return the memory address and message:

```
        >>> import pylab
        >>> import numpy as np
        >>> import matplotlib
        >>> x = np.linspace(0, 20, 1000)
        >>> y = np.sin(x)
        >>> pylab.plot(x, y)
        [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7ff7ac2d5890>]
```

I'm running Kali linux 1.0.7, what do you guys think could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `pylab.show()` in order to render the plot, the rest of your code is correct.

```
>>> import pylab
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib
>>> x = np.linspace(0, 20, 1000)
>>> y = np.sin(x)
>>> pylab.plot(x, y)
>>> pylab.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just add `pylab.show()`!! This will show the plot once the code is run.